# How to force startup of WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have an IIS hosted WCF service, and a client Windows application which, upon the first use of the day, takes a while to respond to the first service call. I believe this to be because IIS shuts down services which are not used for a period of time *(and the delay is the restart time for the service)*. I was wondering whether I could alleviate this by making an asynch call when my application starts up *(just to, potentially, get the service to start)*. I therefore, upon application start, created a "fire and forget" background thread which just opens a connection to the service. The intention being that when my application has finished its own startup, and wants to use the WCF service, the thread will *(probably)* have finished and the service startup delay will not be encountered by the user.

Is this reasonable ? Is opening a channel to the WCF service enough, on its own, to start the service, or do I need to write some dummy method and call that ?

Thanks

Ross

Comment: you can refer this link..
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/11/why-does-wcf-become-slow-after-being-idle-for-15-seconds.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check if you really want your app to handle this task and checkout the [AppWarm-Up Module](http://blogs.iis.net/steveschofield/archive/2012/04/03/app-warm-up-module-released-for-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx) for IIS, maybe you can use this without adding code to your serivce.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this reasonable ?

It doesn't sound like a good approach to me. If you have control over how the service is hosted I would advise you to self-host it.